# Is there a mathematical notation for restricting the depth of a factorial?

Tags: notation, factorial

Say I only want to go $3$ "levels" deep for $5!$ and end up with just $5\times 4\times 3$. Is there a notation for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this is called a "[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)":

$$
n^{\underline{3}} = n(n-1)(n-2)
$$
for example.

I pronounce $n^{\underline{3}}$ as "$n$ fall $3$".

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Make sure to define it before use, because it's nowhere near as recognizable as $5!/2!$.

Comment: Another notation is $(n)_k$, though confusingly, this can also in some contexts refer to the _rising_ factorial power instead, which otherwise would be denoted $n^{(k)}$..

Comment: It's interesting to know that it exists, but it looks like a very dangerous notation. It seems really easy to oversee the underline, and think it's a normal exponent. The two other answers don't have this problem. Still, it's technically a correct answer.

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, you could write
$$
\frac{5!}{2!} \, ,
$$
with the $2!$ cancelling out the unwanted terms. This is actually quite common. For example, it can be used to interpret the '$n$ choose $r$' formula:
$$
{n \choose r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} \, .
$$
Say you have $n$ objects and you want to pick $r$ of them. Then, you have $n$ choices at first, then $(n-1), (n-2), \ldots ,$ and finally $(n-r+1)$. This gives us the
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}
$$
part of the formula. Then, the $r!$ removes duplicates.

Answer (score 14):

This is also sometimes called "permutations of 3 out of 5 things" and denoted 5P3. You can find this on TI-8x calculators, at least, as nPr in the MATH->PRB menu (so you'd type 5 nPr 3).

I have also seen the falling factorial denoted  with brackets as $[5]_3$. I'd say any notation for this will have to be clarified when you use it, though.

Comment: +1 This is by far the most common notation, so it's weird that this answer is at the bottom.